# ¿Como recorrer un array multidimensional con un foreach?

Tags: javascript, array-bidimensional

hola muy buenas pues veran tengo un array multidimensional que tengo que recorrer, he sido capaz de recorrelo con un for pero no tengo ni idea de como recorrelo con un foreach para que el resultado quede exactmante igual que cuando lo recorro con un for. Tiene que quedar un resultado como el que aparece en la imagen que es el que imprimo con el for.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuacion adjunto el codigo javascript que llevo hasta el momento.Se que probablemente no deberia estar preguntando esto dado que es algo sencillo, pero ya llevo varios intentos y no consigo entender como hacerlo

```
var datos = [
    [1, 'dato1', 'description del dato1'],
    [2, 'dato2', 'description del dato2'],
    [3, 'dato3', 'description del dato3'],
    [4,'dato4','description del dato4']
];

datos.forEach(function(num){
        document.write("ELEMENTOS :"+num+"<hr>");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás hablando de arrays dentro de otro array, por lo tanto también tienen posiciones. En cada uno de los arrays internos hay tres elementos, que son las posiciones `0`, `1` y `2`. El `num` del `forEach` te da cada uno de los arrays internos así que con poner `num[0]` ya estás haciendo referencia a la primera posición, y así con los otros dos.

Ahora, si quieres que quede exactamente igual a la imagen, puedes usar un índice auxiliar para contar las iteraciones.

Esto debería funcionar:

```
let index = 0;
datos.forEach(function(num){
    document.write('ELEMENTO ' + index + ':' + num[0] + ' ' + num[1] + ' ' + num[2] + '<hr>');
    index++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Indica dónde aparecerá la lista, con `document.getElementById("vista")` (por lo cual debe haber un **div** con id: `vista`) y escribe con `.innerHTML`.

**Importante**: no uses `document.write()` porque esto reescribirá todo lo que tienes en tu HTML5.

```html
 

<div id="vista"></div>

<script>
var datos = [
 [1, 'dato1', 'description del dato1'],
 [2, 'dato2', 'description del dato2'],
 [3, 'dato3', 'description del dato3'],
 [4,'dato4','description del dato4']
];

datos.forEach(function(num){
    document.getElementById("vista").innerHTML = num;
});
</script>
```

Comment: muchas gracias @Narciso Aifuz